# Adding Progress Bar or Progress Dialogue for sending and receiving file

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have implemented a file sharing project. I am able to Send and Receive File but want to add progress bar or progress dialogue but I have no clue where to add progress bar to it.

Receiver Activity

```
public class ReceiverActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FileReceiver fileReceiver;
    ImageButton ibt;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
             /*   case FileReceiver.CODE :
                    tvCode.setText((int)msg.obj + "");
                    break;
*/
                case FileReceiver.LISTENING :
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Listening...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case FileReceiver.CONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case FileReceiver.RECEIVING_FILE :
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Receiving File!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case FileReceiver.FILE_RECEIVED :
                    File file = (File) msg.obj;
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,file.getName() + " Received!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Stored in " + file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fileReceiver.close();
                    break;

                case FileReceiver.RECEIVE_ERROR :
                    Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Error occured : " + (String)msg.obj,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fileReceiver.close();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void getFile(View view) {

        fileReceiver = new FileReceiver(this,mHandler);

        fileReceiver.getFile();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receiver);

        ibt= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
        ibt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(ReceiverActivity.this, Selection_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Receiver Thread

```
public class ReceiverThread extends Thread {

    private int port;
    private Messenger messenger;
    private ServerSocket listenerSocket;
    private Socket communicationSocket;
    private int PKT_SIZE = 60*1024;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    public ReceiverThread(int port,Messenger messenger){

//



        this.port = port;
        this.messenger = messenger;
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FileSharer/");

        folder.mkdirs();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Message message;

        try {
            listenerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.CODE;
            message.obj = port;
            messenger.send(message);

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.LISTENING;
            message.obj = "";
            messenger.send(message);

            communicationSocket = listenerSocket.accept();

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.CONNECTED;
            message.obj = "";
            messenger.send(message);


            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(communicationSocket.getInputStream());

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.RECEIVING_FILE;
            message.obj = "";
            messenger.send(message);

            // Read File Name and create Output Stream
            String fileName = in.readUTF();

            File receiveFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FileSharer/" + fileName);

            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(receiveFile,true));

            // Read File Size
            long fileSize = in.readLong();

            int totalLength = 0;
            int length = 0;
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[PKT_SIZE];

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // Get the file data
            while( fileSize>0 && ( ( length = in.read( receiveData,0,(int) Math.min(receiveData.length,fileSize) ))!= -1) )
            {
                dout.write(receiveData, 0, length);

                totalLength += length;

                fileSize -= length;
            }

            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            dout.close();

            double time = (stopTime - startTime) / 1000.0;

            double speed = (totalLength / time) / 1048576.0;

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.FILE_RECEIVED;
            message.obj = receiveFile;

            messenger.send(message);

        } catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

            message = Message.obtain();
            message.what = FileReceiver.RECEIVE_ERROR;
            message.obj = e.toString();

            try {
                messenger.send(message);
            } catch (RemoteException re) {
                Log.e("ReceiverThread","Error in sending an error message! Error : " + re.toString());
                re.printStackTrace();
            }

        } finally {

            try {

                if(communicationSocket!=null)
                    communicationSocket.close();

                if(listenerSocket!=null)
                    listenerSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("ReceiverThread","Error in closing sockets. Error : " + ioe.toString());
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Receiver Service

```
public class ReceiverService extends Service {

    private final String PORT = "PORT";
    private final String MESSENGER = "MESSENGER";

    private int port;
    private Messenger messenger;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        port = (int) b.get(PORT);
        messenger = (Messenger) b.get(MESSENGER);

        ReceiverThread receiverThread = new ReceiverThread(port,messenger);

        receiverThread.start();

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

File Receiver

```
public class FileReceiver {

    private final boolean mDebug = true;

//    private final int MIN_PORT_NUMBER = 1024;
  //  private final int MAX_PORT_NUMBER = 65536;
    private final String PORT = "PORT";
    private final String MESSENGER = "MESSENGER";

    // Constants start from 2001
    public static final int CODE = 2001;
    public static final int LISTENING = 2002;
    public static final int CONNECTED = 2003;
    public static final int RECEIVING_FILE = 2004;
    public static final int FILE_RECEIVED = 2005;
    public static final int RECEIVE_ERROR = 2006;

    private Context context;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private Intent i;

    public FileReceiver(Context context, Handler mHandler) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

/*    private boolean isPortAvailable(int port) {

        boolean available;

        if (port < MIN_PORT_NUMBER || port > MAX_PORT_NUMBER) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid port: " + port);
        }

        ServerSocket ss = null;

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            ss.setReuseAddress(true);
            available = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            available = false;
        } finally {

            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }

        return available;
    }
*/
    private int getRandomPort() {
 //int port = 1001;
        int port = 40500;

        //do{
          //  port = (int) (MIN_PORT_NUMBER + 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*(MAX_PORT_NUMBER - MIN_PORT_NUMBER-1)));

            if(mDebug)
                Log.i("FileReceiver","Trying port : " + port);

//        }while(!isPortAvailable(port));

        return port;


 //   return port;
    }

    public void getFile(){

        int port = getRandomPort();

        if(mDebug)
            Log.i("FileReceiver","Port : " + port);

        i = new Intent(context,ReceiverService.class);

        i.putExtra(PORT,port);
        i.putExtra(MESSENGER,new Messenger(mHandler));

        context.startService(i);

    }

    public void close() {
        context.stopService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me the progress dialog is the best choice to do what you whant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a simple `ProgressDialog` box from your activity.

Something like :

```
// global variable 
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

...
...

// inside onCreate
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ReceiveActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file ..");

...
...

// before file downloads
mProgressDialog.show();

...
...

// when file is downloaded
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

**Edit :**

In case of the given questions, this can be done as :

```
// assuming mProgressDialog is already initialised and configured.

          case FileReceiver.CONNECTED:
                Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /******** Show the dialog box *********/
                mProgressDialog.show(); // make sure that the file receiving starts immediately
                                        // after the receiver is connected and that it do not
                                        // require any action (like button click) after is connected

                break;

            case FileReceiver.RECEIVING_FILE :
                Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Receiving File!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /******** Dismiss the dialog box *********/
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                break;

            case FileReceiver.FILE_RECEIVED :
                File file = (File) msg.obj;
                Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,file.getName() + " Received!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(ReceiverActivity.this,"Stored in " + file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fileReceiver.close();

                /******** Dismiss the dialog box *********/
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                break;
```

You can also have a dialog box with progress percentage. Have a look into the [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) documentation.

There are methods like `setProgressStyle(int style)` with values like `STYLE_HORIZONTAL`. And then there are `incrementProgressBy(int diff)` that can be used to get a horizontal bar there.

Comment: To be specific, where should I place the code of progress bar in above posted receiver activity because the downloading/receiving has four sections, the receiver activity, receiver thread , receiver service and file reciever

Comment: This should probably be inside the `switch(){}` in your `Receiver activity`. `show()` the progress box in `case` of `FileReceiver.CONNECTED` and `dismiss()` it in `case` of `FileReceiver.FILE_RECEIVED` and `FileReceiver.RECEIVE_ERROR`

Comment: Thank you so much ZeekHuge, but I would like to know is it possible to show percentage on the progress dialog??